# i don't understand the one-liner haskell fibonacci

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, fibonacci

this one:

```
fib = 1 : 1 : [a + b | (a, b) <- zip fib (tail fib)]
```

i understand that at first `fib` is [1, 1, ..]

(`..` = rest of the list)

so here `fib` = `[1, 1, ..]` and `tail fib` = `[1, ..]` so `(a, b)` is `(1, 1)` which translate to `a + b` which is `2` and now the list looks like that:

```
fib = 1 : 1 : 2 : [a + b | (a, b) <- zip fib (tail fib)]
```

and here i get confused:

now i think `fib` is `[1, 1, 2, ..]` and `tail fib` is `[1, 2, ..]`
and if i `zip` the lists, i again should get that `a + b` is `1 + 1` because those are still the first elements of the two lists.
where am i wrong here?

(i know i am but i can't understand why and what is going on here)

Comment: i asked already there but i think no one see this post anymore :-)

Comment: There are plenty of great answers there. A question being inactive isn't a good reason to ask it again. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: i know there are but there is something i can't understand here. i tried as you see to ask there but didn't get any answer.

Comment: I'm partial to `fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` personally.

Comment: I don't see any "good" answers at the linked entry, at all. By "good" I mean such that I could understand, if I didn't already know the answer (as I do). this includes my own answer which I've now deleted.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41917154/4) for an illustration.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that

```
fib = 1 : 1 : [a + b | (a, b) <- zip fib (tail fib)]
```

produces the next element to be 2. However, `fib = 1 : 1 : 2 : [a + b | (a, b) <- zip fib (tail fib)]` is not accurate for the next step. Since you evaluate `zip fib (tail fib)` on this step, it must be substituted from its definition, not left as it is. A more accurate formula looks something like:

```
fib = 1 : 1 : 2 : [a + b | (a, b) <- zip (tail fib) (tail (tail fib)]
```

One way to think of the evaluation of `zip` is that each application consumes the next two head elements of each of the given lists. In this case, the next iteration will return `(a, b) = (1, 2)` since this is the next pair of numbers in `fib` and `(tail fib)` respectively.

Comment: what is confusing is that fib changing all the time. it's not two lists that i know already and i zip them together. in the list comprehension i "call" fib every iteration and it's different in every "call".

Comment: @moshe Your assessment is incorrect. You "call" `fib` **once** as a parameter to `zip`. Then `zip` is evaluated and consumes `fib`.

Comment: @moshe Also remember that Haskell uses lazy evaluation. The elements in the list `fib` are evaluated as `zip` asks for them. This is the main reason why this solution works.

Comment: thanks!. so am i right that `fib` is always the *full* list, but `zip` "knows" it already chopped the heads of `fib` and `tail fib` so it moves on to the next "pair"?

Comment: @moshe Yes, that is the correct way to think about it. As an exercise, I suggest you write your own version of `zip`. Then using that definition, evaluate some examples by hand.

Comment: thank you very much for you help :-)